# How to create a pageContext in google app engine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets

To create a page context programmatically in our servlets we do the following:

```
JspFactory factory = JspFactory.getDefaultFactory();

PageContext pageContext = factory.getPageContext(this, request, response, 
            "404", true, 4096, false);
```

This works fine on tomcat and the dev gae environment. However when deploying the app to the live environment  JspFactory.getDefaultFactory() returns null.

Header of web.xml has the following:

```
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
```

Does anyone know how to create a PageContext programmatically on google app engine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read it somewhere. Google APP Engine looks to use Tomcat behind.This looks like a bug. A workaround would be is set the default factory using
`Class.forName("org.apache.jasper.compiler.JspRuntimeContext");`